# Does the blacking out generator has effect on the final performance of the model?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am running my *own* model as a generator and discriminator for generator adversarial networks. The generator creates fake images after every 10 epochs and I need to run a total of 800 epochs. I am facing the following issue several times

> After (say) 200 epochs, the generator starts creating blank images and
> suddenly nice images after 300 epochs. And this happens randomly several times.

For example: (200 epoch)[image]

(201 -299) epochs

[image]

I don't know the exact reason why it is happening, I am guessing two reasons. The first reason is the presence of `nan` values during training. The second reason may be the memory issues due to GPU. I am strongly believing that the first one may be the reason.

In that case, if I run my model 800 epochs and then calculate the performance of the model then can I capture the exact performance or there will be an issue with the `nan` values in the intermediate epochs?

The main reason for asking this question is that I cannot stop the execution of my program suddenly and check what is the issue as I am running on my University system and I need to submit it only once and I need to wait till it completes execution.

Comment: When it is judged that the picture is blank, the result is output.

Comment: So, do you mean, the performance is affected after the 800th epoch? @lazy

Comment: sorry, print result and feature etc.

Comment: So you can check why the blank picture appears.

Comment: Your examples confuse me. To me, both of the images look "blank". Are any of them supposed to be "nice"? What do your losses look like? What model are you using? It's very hard to give proper help if we (literally) stare at a black box.

Comment: @André All the examples I provided are not nice.  Nice images are up to 199 epochs and after 300 epoch,

Comment: @André I am expecting/hoping that someone might already face it.

Comment: if you are generating the outputs with random latent variables and what you get as output is the same for all of them that basically may be due to using ReLU which kills some of your neurons and thus your output is always you last later bias or that your model during optimization made all of the wights of a layer or the whole model zeros. I hope this insight will be helpful

Comment: if you can provide info about you model and your losses I might be able to help. Btw getting a nan for loss (depends on where you get it) might be due to a problem with your discriminator... it might be giving very small probabilities to your data or close to 1 prob. to your generated data assuming you are using KL divergence.

Comment: @D.ACAR Loss is Hinge. But, it may take time for me to add print statements and check the log file.

Comment: @D.ACAR I will surely post whenever I got access to the system.

Comment: how are you training a GAN with hinge loss. Do you use it for both the generator and discriminator? please check KL divergence, Jensen Shannon divergence or wasserstien losses.

Comment: you need to estimate the distance between your data distribution and your generator distribution for that you need to use proper distance measures

Comment: implementation of KL divergence is pretty easy please check and try that.

Comment: if you can wait for 3 hours I can provide a code snippet on how you can train it given a generator and discriminator. I think the training procedure that you have implemented is wrong.

Comment: @D.ACAR Sure. Thanks.

Comment: Hi sorry I realized that I cannot test the procedure that I am writing (I am training a model in my cluster) so instead I looked for a good explanation for how to do it... [please see this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) if you would have any questions you can write them here. I would try to explain them.